# jQuery not logging event or performing function

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, jquery-events

```
$('.logoTop').on('click', 'img', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    if ($(".navTop").css("top", "-100px")) {
        $(".navTop").css("top", "0px");
    }
    else{
        $(".navTop").css("top", "-100px")
    }
});
```

This is my code, where `.logoTop` is an image, but when I click on it, nothing happens and the console does not even log an event.

Edit: The function is contained within the `$(document).ready()` and other functions are working properly.

Note: I use other jQuery functions to add and remove class names before this function.

Comment: What is the html of `logoTop`?

Comment: @CDspace logoTop was added using "$(".logo").removeClass("logo").addClass("logoTop");"

Answer (score 2):

If .logoTop is the class of the image it will never fire, because you are basically saying this :

*In the element with a class name logoTop find an image and wait for the click event*.

There is no image inside your image tag, so your code should be like this

```
$('body').on('click', '.logoTop', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    if ($(".navTop").css("top", "-100px")) {
        $(".navTop").css("top", "0px");
    }
    else{
        $(".navTop").css("top", "-100px")
    }
});
```

Or simply (Note that the first example will work for dynamically created elements)

```
$('.logoTop').on('click', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    if ($(".navTop").css("top", "-100px")) {
        $(".navTop").css("top", "0px");
    }
    else{
        $(".navTop").css("top", "-100px")
    }
});
```

Comment: Or just remove the `'img'` (second) parameter, leaving: `$('.logoTop').on('click', function (event) { ...`. Seems unnecessary to delegate this one to the `body`, **unless the `.logoTop`s don't all exist at the time you bind this handler**. OP, you can learn all about delegation (and why your original code was incorrect) in [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Yes you are right, I am just following his concept and how it can be done to work :) I will make both examples :)

Comment: Also slightly on/off topic, an interesting read & performance test for whether `$('body')` is really the best element to delegate to (vs `$(document)`, etc): http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-body-on-document-on/

Comment: This worked, thanks! But when I click the ".logoTop" again, the ".navTop" does not go back to -100px.

Comment: Your if statement is wrong, it should be if ($(".navTop").css("top") == "-100px") :)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, but at the end I decided to go with toggleClass and add another class to my CSS to do this.